# CoreData - fetch only tasks that have a day (to-many relationship)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I spent some time searching for an answer to my question but I couldn't find any (probably due to the fact that I don't really know what exactly to look for).

I have tasks and days. Each task can have multiple days, and each day can have multiple tasks.

I want to grab all tasks that have no days and put them into a tableView. Thus, I'm using the `NSFetchedResultsController` class. I think I need to add some kind of `NSPredicate`. I tried this:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Task> = Task.fetchRequest()
let filterPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "days.count == 0")
fetchRequest.predicate = filterPredicate
....
```

But it throws an error

> "to-many key not allowed here"

How can I only fetch tasks that have no days?

Thank you

Comment: Try `"days.@count == 0"`

Comment: So, I'm not quite sure if this works. It doesn't crash for this reason anymore, at least. But when I add a task to a day at runtime, the app crashes with an error: "attempt to delete row 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update". Is it because the fetchedResultsController automatically removes that row (because now the task has a day)?

Comment: Okay, that above-mentioned error was not caused by this. It works now, thank you :)